# How do I marshal a stream for COM

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, com

I am consuming a COM object written in Delphi that requires a Stream.

The interface generated by VS requests a parameter of type "object"

```
comReader.LoadFromStream(object stream)
```

When I use a FileStream or MemoryStream I get an "Invalid argument"-exception.

How do I marshal a stream for COM consummation?

Comment: What type is the parameter according to the COM type library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should create wrapper for .Net Stream that implements COM `IStream` interface

See this [article](http://www.sturmnet.org/blog/2005/03/03/cds-csharp-extractor) (There is partly implementation)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** I found this interesting answer:  **[How do I declare an IStream in idl so visual studio maps it to s.w.interop.comtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691086/how-do-i-declare-an-istream-in-idl-so-visual-studio-maps-it-to-s-w-interop-comty)**

Basically what you want to do is to implement [`System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.istream.aspx) or use an existing implementing class.

If all else fails You should be able to marshal arbitrary data using UnmanagedMemoryStream. ([MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))