# How to pass InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream to native method accepting IStream* using c++/cli

Tags: c++, com, c++-cli

I have a native dll with a managed wrapper, all written and working with COM interop. My job now is to rewrite the wrapper (and parts of the dll) using c++/cli.

One of the methods in native dll accepts a pointer **IStream* output** as one of it's arguments, and that is where I am stuck. Whenever I try to use the pointer **output**, I get an **AccessViolationException**.

Here is an illustration of what my code looks like:

common.h

```
class INativeClass
{
public:
    virtual int NativeMethod(IStream* output) = 0;
};
```

c++ native

```
#include "common.h"

public NativeClass : public INativeClass  
{  
    public int NativeMethod(IStream* output)  
    {  
        outputStream->Write(...); //AccessViolationException happens here
    }  
}
```

c++ managed

```
#include "common.h"

public ref class ManagedClass  
{  
private:  
    INativeClass* nativeObject;  

public: 

    ManagedClass()  
    {  
        nativeObject = CreateNewNativeObject();  
    }  

    int ManagedMethod(IStream^ output)  
    {  
        NativeClass nativeObject = new 
        GCHandle streamHandle = GCHandle::Alloc(output);  
        IntPtr ipo = GCHandle::ToIntPtr(streamHandle);  
        nativeObject->NativeMethod(static_cast<IStream*>(ipo.ToPointer()));  
    }  
}
```

c#

```
void main()  
{  
    ManagedClass managedObject = new ManagedClass();  
    IStreamImplementation stream = new IStreamImplementation(filepath);  
    managedObject.ManagedMethod(stream);  
}
```

I have been searching the internet for a few days now, and can't seem to find what I am doing wrong. I think I have converted to **IStream*** properly, and that I shouldn't have to worry about the GC. I also tried using **pin_ptr**, but it didn't help.

If this is a duplicate, I apologise, but as I said, I have been searching for the solution for a few days already.

**EDIT**

Updated the code with the minimal compilable code that reproes the issue (might be missing a few includes).
Also when I say IStream, I mean InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream or it's c++ counterpart. I am not using std::istream

Comment: These are the articles you are looking for. [How do I marshal a stream for COM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7849722/9014308), [An implementation of a Copernic Desktop Search Custom Extractor in C#](https://oliversturm.com/2005/03/03/cds-csharp-extractor/), [How do I declare an IStream in idl so visual studio maps it to s.w.interop.comtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2691086/9014308), [UnmanagedMemoryStream Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Do you have a small reproducing code? Devil can hide in details.

Comment: @kunif I should have mentioned, but it seems I forgot. When I say IStream, I mean InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream, or the c++ equivalent. (not std::istream) The articles you sent me seem to be telling me to use ComTypes.IStream (which I already am), or telling me how to read unmanaged stream in managed code (while I need to do the opposite. I am not sure if I am missing something?

Comment: These articles may be helpful. [Chapter 8. IStreamとOleLoadPicture](http://atata.sakura.ne.jp/com/chap8.html), [simplestream.h](http://atata.sakura.ne.jp/com/chap8_3.html), [simplestream.cpp](http://atata.sakura.ne.jp/com/chap8_4.html) Although it is Japanese, it will be readable by Google translation. Here is an example of a wrapper in C# instead of C++. [Does a wrapper class for a COM interop IStream already exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2586159/9014308) You may be able to do something when combined.

Comment: @SimonMourier I have updated the code

Comment: There are still some missing parts (x86 vs x86, calling convention stdcall vs cdecl, etc.). It would be better to put a .zip somewhere with the full reproducing problem.

Comment: Wrong pointer, as you might have guessed.  GCHandle is not useful at all.  The IStream^ reference points to the RCW for IStream*.  You can dig out the native interface pointer with Marhal::GetIUnknownForObject().  Cast the returned IntPtr to IUnknown*, then QueryInterface for IID_IStream.  Ought to take two Release() calls.  Or [use this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatestreamonfileex).

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, the part about extracting the native pointer helped me! I just don't get the part about Release().
Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem by doing what Hans Passant said:

In ManagedClass, I have:

```
int ManagedMethod (IStream^ output)
{
    IntPtr outputPtr = Marshal::GetIUnknownForObject(output);
    IUnknown* outputNativePtr = static_cast<IUnknown*>(outputPtr.ToPointer());
    nativeObject->NativeMethod(outputNativePtr);
}
```

In NativeClass I have:

```
int NativeMethod(IUnknown* output)
{
    IStream outputStream;
    HRESULT hr = output->QueryInterface(IID_IStream, (void**)&outputStream);
    if (FAILED(hr) || outputStream == nullptr)
    {
        //error
    }
    //do something
}
```